# Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive defined real diagonal matrices, find $\max_{U} \det(I_n+UAU'B)$ for all real unitary matrix $U$.

Tags: matrices

This problem seems to be simple in a first glance but I struggle it for several days:

Let $A=\mathbb{diag}\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $B=\mathbb{diag}\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ be two positive definite real diagonal matrices, find $\max_{U} \det(I_n+UAU'B)$ for all real unitary matrix $U$.

The maximum attains at $U=I_n$, but I don't know how to prove it..

Comment: Do you mean "positive definite" instead of "positive defined"?